Azure tag values missing when querying with powershell
I'm currently trying to do an export to csv of tag values from Azure VMs, but running into issues with blank outputs. I'm on the latest version of PowerShell 7 and have updated the AZ modules.
Both the screen print and the csv show the tag values empty for nearly half of the resources, but all resources show that they have tags in the webUI. The results are the same mixed level of success whether I'm filtering on the Technical POC key or outputting all tags for that resource.
#Sample code to filter and output a specific key
$tagKey = "Technical POC"  # Replace with the key of the tag you want to retrieve
            if ($tags.ContainsKey($tagKey)) {
                Write-Warning "The value of the tag '$tagKey' is: $($tags[$tagKey])"

#Sample code to format for the csv
$vmdetail = [PSCustomObject]@{
     SubscriptionId    = $subscription.Id
     SubscriptionName  = $subscription.Name
     ResourceGroupName = $VMResource.ResourceGroupName
     VMName            = $VMResource.Name
     TechnicalPOC      = $($tags[$tagKey])


Screen output when the is a value but it doesnt show up (FAILURE EXAMPLE)
WARNING: testvm1
WARNING: Getting VM Tags
WARNING: Tags Recieved
WARNING: The value of the tag 'Technical POC' is: 

Screen output when there is no tag assigned (SUCCESSFUL EXAMPLE)
WARNING: testvm2
WARNING: Getting VM Tags
WARNING: Tags Recieved
WARNING: Tag 'Technical POC' not found on the VM.


Screen output when there is no tag assigned (SUCCESSFUL EXAMPLE)
WARNING: testvm3
WARNING: Getting VM Tags
WARNING: Tags Recieved
WARNING: The value of the tag 'Technical POC' is: john.smith@domain.com




You may be having an issue when $tags only has one item.  Try @($tags[$tagKey]) while will force a single item into an array.


Azure tag values missing when querying with PowerShell

I tried an updated PowerShell script which helps in retrieving the VM details with specific tags can be achieved.
PowerShell script:
$tagKey = "env"
$tagValue = "test"

$vms = Get-AzVM
$vmDetails = @()

foreach ($vm in $vms) {
   
    if ($vm.Tags -ne $null -and $vm.Tags.ContainsKey($tagKey) -and $vm.Tags[$tagKey] -eq $tagValue) {
    
        $vmDetails += [PSCustomObject]@{
            VMName            = $vm.Name
            ResourceGroupName = $vm.ResourceGroupName
            SubscriptionId    = $vm.Id.Split('/')[2]
            SubscriptionName  = $vm.Tags[$tagKey]
        }
    }
}


$vmDetails | Export-CSV -Path "bol.csv"

Output:


Refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvm?view=azps-12.2.0
